# Laravel when adding foreign id i'm getting: 'Failed to open the referenced table'

Tags: php, laravel

in my migration folder first migration file is:

```
2014_10_11_000000_create_user_properties_table
```

and i have this `schema` into that:

```php
Schema::create('user_properties', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained()->nullable()->onDelete('cascade');

    $table->mediumText('province')->nullable();
    
    $table->timestamp('created_at')->useCurrent();
    $table->timestamp('updated_at')->useCurrent();
});
```

and second migration file is:

```
2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table
```

and i have this `schema` into that too:

```php
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained()->nullable();

    /*$table->foreignId('properties_id')->constrained('user_properties')->nullable();*/

    $table->boolean('active')->default(0);
    $table->string('name')->nullable();
    $table->string('family')->nullable();
    $table->string('username')->unique();

    ///...
    
    $table->timestamp('created_at')->useCurrent();
    $table->timestamp('updated_at')->useCurrent();
});
```

now when i uncommenting this line:

```php
$table->foreignId('properties_id')->constrained('user_properties')->nullable();
```

which that's into `users` Schema and i try to run migration command i get this error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1824 Failed to open the referenced table 'users' (SQL: alter table `user_properties` add constraint `user_properties_user_id_foreign` foreign key (`user_id`) references `users` (`id`) on delete cascade)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [General error: 1824 Failed to open the referenced table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60826299/general-error-1824-failed-to-open-the-referenced-table)

Answer (score 2):

First, You are trying to refer the `users` table inside the `user_properties` migration file when in fact the `users` table doesn't exist yet.
The second schematic problem is the timestamps of your migration files. Laravel refers migration files in alphabetical order and will try to execute `user_properties` migration **before** the `users`'s one.

From my understanding, you are trying to create a one-to-many relationship between the user and the user's properties. In this case, I think the right flow will be something like this -

1. `php artisan make:migration create_users_table`
2. inside the create_users_table migration file your scheme shouldn't include any foreign ids -

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {

    $table->id();
    $table->boolean('active')->default(0);
    $table->string('name')->nullable();
    $table->string('family')->nullable();
    $table->string('username')->unique();

    ///...
    
    $table->timestamp('created_at')->useCurrent();
    $table->timestamp('updated_at')->useCurrent();
});
```

3. `php artisan migrate`
4. `php artisan make:migration create_user_properties_table`
5. inside the create_user_properties_table migration file you should enter this -

```
Schema::create('user_properties', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->foreignId('user_id')->nullable();
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');

    $table->mediumText('province')->nullable();
    
    $table->timestamp('created_at')->useCurrent();
    $table->timestamp('updated_at')->useCurrent();
});
```

6. `php artisan migrate` once again
7. In case you'd like to emphasise laravel's eloquent approach and access user's properties in a easy way like `$user->property->province` then you should create a relationship between their models as well.

In User.php (I guess it resides on App/Models/User.php or any other path you've chosen for your models) you should add this method -

```
    public function property()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(UserProperties::class);
    }
```

And in UserProperties.php you should add

```
    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
```

So in case you have some specific property that you'd like to retrieve its' user - it will be very easy and approachable as well.

Comment: ok. i have `2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table.php` in first and `2014_10_12_000001_create_user_properties_table.php` as second file, now after deleting `timestamp` from `user_properties` i get this error: `General error: 1824 Failed to open the referenced table 'user_properties' (SQL: alter table users add constraint user_properties_id_foreign foreign key (properties_id) references user_properties (id))`

Comment: The best approach would be to re-create these migration files in the right order, using ```php artisan make:migration create_users_table```, insert all your queries there, but please note that you **can't** refer the user_properties table there since it wasn't created yet. then ```php artisan migrate``` and then execute the same process for the user_properties table.

Comment: I edited my answer according to the last comment. please let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your reference schema hasn't been created when you're trying to create your `users` schema. Look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60826299/general-error-1824-failed-to-open-the-referenced-table), it might solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:**

---

In the case two tables referring to each other, you can not use foreign key when creating table. Because, you will get an error when you are trying to refer to a table that has not been created yet.

**Solution:**

---

To solve this issue, you could generate 4 migration files: 2 files for creating tables, 2 files for adding foreign keys:

1. You create **1st table** but you do not use any foreign keys
2. You create **2nd table** but you do not use any foreign keys
3. You add only foreign keys for **1st table**
4. You add only foreign keys for **2nd table**